# typoscript condition GP not done

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I encountered such a problem in the script. I have a condition but it does not work. I do not understand why I tried different meanings but did not help anything. Who can say why?
I used Typo3 6.2

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_store_storelocatorframe|store != 0]
```

Also, when the value is displayed in this way, then I get the correct result in the browser.

```
page.10.wrap.data = GP:tx_store_storelocatorframe|store
```

The reason may be that the value is of the **String** type ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following condition/ operator. If needed, you can add an else branch to check what's going on.

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_store_storelocatorframe|store > 0]
    ...
[else]
    ...
[end]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem since conditions always return false

Comment: What do you mean by saying your value is of type string? This does not make much sense. It is a number right? That is tx_store_storelocatorframe[store] could be for example 12. Right?